# I'm trying to remove nested list which contains bounding box values. I'm using easyocr library to extract the text and bounding box values

Tags: python, list, ocr, nested-lists, bounding-box

```
bounds = reader.readtext(np.array(images[0]), min_size=0, slope_ths=0.2, ycenter_ths=0.7, height_ths=0.6, width_ths=0.8,decoder='beamsearch', beamWidth=10)
print(bounds)
```

[([[1002, 126], [1210, 126], [1210, 222], [1002, 222]],
'uz5',
0.048652395606040955),
([[177, 179], [349, 179], [349, 241], [177, 241]],
'OIZI',
0.7936368584632874),
([[180, 236], [422, 236], [422, 268], [180, 268]],
'Oki Electric Industry Co',
0.4165174067020416)]

```
print(bounds[0][0])
```

[[1002, 126], [1210, 126], [1210, 222], [1002, 222]]

**How to remove the nested list and make a flat list for all the bounding box values in 'bounds' variable?**

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you're getting and what you expect?

Comment: No, what I'm trying to say is removing nested list from one list. I mean we have bounding box values, text and confidence right. In bounding box, we have nested lists. Can we remove that nested list and make it flat list for example? [([1002, 126, 1210, 126, 1210, 222, 1002, 222], 'uz5', 0.048652395606040955)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach makes a `list` which reduces the nested list into a flattened list found in the first element -> `bound[0]` of each entry of bounds, the other elements are unpacked in the tuple, after the flattened list.

```
bounds = [([[1002, 126], [1210, 126], [1210, 222], [1002, 222]], 'uz5', 0.048652395606040955), ([[177, 179], [349, 179], [349, 241], [177, 241]], 'OIZI', 0.7936368584632874), ([[180, 236], [422, 236], [422, 268], [180, 268]], 'Oki Electric Industry Co', 0.4165174067020416)]

out = [(sum(bound[0], []), *bound[1:]) for bound in bounds]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[([1002, 126, 1210, 126, 1210, 222, 1002, 222], 'uz5', 0.048652395606040955), 
([177, 179, 349, 179, 349, 241, 177, 241], 'OIZI', 0.7936368584632874), 
([180, 236, 422, 236, 422, 268, 180, 268], 'Oki Electric Industry Co', 0.4165174067020416)]
```

Alternatively if you only intented to keep the first flattened list you could do this:

```
bounds = [([[1002, 126], [1210, 126], [1210, 222], [1002, 222]], 'uz5', 0.048652395606040955), ([[177, 179], [349, 179], [349, 241], [177, 241]], 'OIZI', 0.7936368584632874), ([[180, 236], [422, 236], [422, 268], [180, 268]], 'Oki Electric Industry Co', 0.4165174067020416)]

out = [sum(bound[0], []) for bound in bounds]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[1002, 126, 1210, 126, 1210, 222, 1002, 222], 
[177, 179, 349, 179, 349, 241, 177, 241], 
[180, 236, 422, 236, 422, 268, 180, 268]]
```